# Pandas - Ratio between rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I need to find out the **proportion** of the elements of a column relative to a **certain value in this column**. For example, in this Table A I want to find out the ratio of column *Metric* regarding to the value where {*id1=x and id2=z*} of this column. Could anyone help me, please?

For example:

Table A

```
+-------+------+-------+
| id1   | id2  | metric|
+-------+------+-------+
| x     |  z   | 100   |
| x     |  w   | 10    |
+-------+------+-------+
```

Correct Result:

Table B

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+
| id1   | id2  | metric| result|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
| x     |  z   | 100   |  1    | (100/100)
| x     |  w   | 10    |  0.1  | (10/100)
+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Code:

```
d = {'id1': ['x', 'x'], 'id2': ['z','w'], 'metric': [100,10] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Comment: `df['result']=df.metric/100`?

Comment: I need to discover the '100' value in that position automaticaly. In that case was 100 but it was just an example, thist could be any other value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are describing the following:

#### Setup

```
d = {'id1': ['x', 'x'], 'id2': ['z','w'], 'metric': [100,10] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

#### Solution

```
# Manually choose the value by which to scale the column 'metric'
scaler = df.loc[(df['id1'] == 'x') & (df['id2'] == 'z'), 'metric'].values

# Divide all 'metric' values by the above scaler value
df['result'] = df['metric'] / scaler

df
  id1 id2  metric  result
0   x   z     100     1.0
1   x   w      10     0.1
```

Comment: Perfect! Tks! : )